# Linq to Sql - How to get data from second level table

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

I'm newbie to linq to sql, just trying to understand what type of queries I can handle with linq.

Here is my database scheme,

[image]

I want to get all customers of a specific user and this is what I've done,

```
var userId = 4;
var companies = from c in db.Company
                where c.UserId == userId
                select c.Id;

var costumers = from c in db.Customers
                where companies.Contains(c.CompanyId)
                select c;
```

I'm just wondering whether it's a nice approach and is there any better method to handle this type of queries?

Comment: I would create an association: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb629295.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Contains is the equivalent of IN in SQL and your Linq statement will be translated to a SQL statement. So I can't really see another way that will give you better performance with Linq. If you want to use less code you can maybe try the following instead:

```
var companies = db.Companies.Where(x=> x.UserId == userid).Select(x=>x.Id);
var customers = db.Customers.Where(x=> companies.Contains(x.CompanyId));
```

Answer (score 0):

Use can also get customers by this way also:

```cs
  var result = db.Customers.Join(
               db.Company, customer => customer.CompanyId, comp => comp.Id, (customer, comp) 
               => new { customer, comp }).Where(@t => @t.comp.UserId == 4)
               .Select(@t => @t.customer);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also keep it simple like this.

```
 select * from db.Customers Cus
 inner join db.company Com on Com.Id = Cus.CompanyId
 where Com.UserId= userId
```